# Why does this allow promotion from (char *) to (const char *)?

Tags: c

Given that scanf has (const char *) in the [documentation from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkx076cy.aspx) and the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766290/shouldnt-it-be-permissible-to-convert-from-char-to-const-char) what the heck is going when I do the same for (char **) promotion to (const char **)?

Basically why does this compile?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    char szArray[50];
    int  i = 0;
    strcpy(szArray,"10");
    /* the following code is upcasting the (char *) to (const char *) */
    sscanf(szArray,"%d",&i);
    return 0;  
}
```

And why won't this compile?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void processargs(const char **p)
{ 
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    processargs(argv);          
    return 0;  
}
```

Both seem to be doing the same thing to a pointer!

Comment: you dont understand one thing: if T -> U works, then that doesn't mean T* -> U* works. just a simple one: double a = 4; /* int -> double */ int p; double *dp = &p; /* int* -> double* ?? */

Comment: I am not changing types here... both sets are pointers.

Comment: Please close the other one and not this one...

Comment: The number of '*'s matters. Look carefully at palecek's answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`char** -> const char **` is dangerous, since you might end up accidentally modifying the underlying `const` object.

The correct way to write what you want is:

```
void processargs(const char * const *p)
{ 
}
```

Comment: That you can use const this way should be publicized. I don't think that a lot of people know that you can do this.

Answer (score 3):

You're allowed to increase access restriction, you just can't decrease it. Going from a normal pointer to a const pointer is fine, going from a const pointer to a normal pointer is not.

The second example doesn't compile because you're not converting a pointer to a const pointer, you're converting from a pointer to one type (`char*`) to another (`const char*`). For example, you can change a `char**` to a `char* const*`, but not a `const char**`.

Comment: Okay why wont the second example compile then?

Answer (score 2):

Check if this clarifies for you:

```
char * a_mutable = /*...*/;
const char * a_constant = /*...*/;

char **pointer_to_mutable = &a_mutable;   /* ok */

const char **pointer_to_constant = &a_constant;   /* ok */

pointer_to_constant = pointer_to_mutable;   /* oops, are you sure? */

*pointer_to_constant = a_mutable;   /* valid, but will screw things around */
```

The last line is valid, since `pointer_to_constant` is a mutable pointer to a mutable pointer to a constant character, but it would break things since you are making `a_constant` point to `a_mutable`. That is why you are not allowed to make `pointer_to_constant` receive the contents of `pointer_to_mutable`.

Answer (score 0):

The first example of yours works, because you're converting *rvalues* of `char*` to `const char*`, which is OK (basically because you cannot assign to rvalues). The second doesn't, because the target of a (non-const) pointer is always a lvalue.

Just try (maybe with the aid of the compiler) which operations you can do with `char**`, which work with `const char**`, and think if and what types are interchangeable.