# const correctness for execv's argv parameter

Tags: c, constants, implicit-conversion, qualifiers, multiple-indirection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double pointer const-correctness warnings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055655/double-pointer-const-correctness-warnings-in-c)

Look at the table here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html

We see that the following is invalid in C:

```
void f(const char * const argv[])
{
    (void)argv;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void)argc;
    f(argv);
    return 0;
}

test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:9: warning: passing argument 1 of 'f' from incompatible pointer type
test.c:1: note: expected 'const char * const*' but argument is of type 'char **'
```

Why is this invalid? It seems to me that `const char * const argv[]` is just "more constant" than `char * argv []`, (and it's allowed in C++) so why is it invalid in C?

Comment: Did you read this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/766406/1126268

Comment: @Kirilenko I think they're all answering this question: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html (char ** -> const char **), but my question concerns (char ** -> const char **). The former in invalid in C & C++, but the latter is only invalid in C as far as I can tell.

Comment: ecatmur: it is a duplicate of that.